# Method overriding in swift

Tags: swift, overriding

Basically I am currently adding `functionX` to everywhere i present an UIAlertController as seen below:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default)
alert.addAction(okAction)
functionX(actionSheet: alert, controller: self)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
// or it can be
// tableviewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Instead of calling `functionX` every time, I want to override a present method and call `functionX` there. I attempted the following:

```
extension UIViewController {
    override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        if (viewControllerToPresent is UIAlertController) {
            functionX(actionSheet: viewControllerToPresent, controller: /* what should this be? */ )
        }
        super.present() //error here
    }
}
```

Is this an appropriate approach? Can you help me fill the missing parameters?

i.e.:

- What should be the controller? What would `self` or `tableviewController` from the first code stub be in the overriding present function?
- How should I call the `present` method in the overriding present function?

Comment: What is functionX? Do you want to make a central method to present alert?

Comment: functionX is a method i implemented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Swift guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html),

> Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.

So you shouldn't really be overriding an existing method in a `UIViewController` in an extension.

What you could do is, to add your own `present`, called `functionXAndPresent`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func functionXAndPresent(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        if (viewControllerToPresent is UIAlertController) {
            // to answer your second question, you should use "self" here
            functionX(actionSheet: viewControllerToPresent, controller: self)
        }
        present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

You can't do this by overriding because as you have found out, you can't really refer to the "non-overridden" method at the end. `super.present` doesn't work because you are in an extension, not a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a common method `showAlert(with:and:)` in a `UIViewController` `extension` and call `functionX` when the `alert` is presented, i.e.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showAlert(with title: String?, message: String?) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
            self.functionX(actionSheet: alert, controller: self)
        })
    }

    func functionX(actionSheet: UIAlertController, controller: UIViewController) {
        //your code here...
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

Call the `showAlert(with:and:)` method from whatever controller you want to, be it a `UIViewController` or a `UITableViewController` or any other, i.e

```
self.showAlert(with: "Alery..!!!", message: "This is a sample alert.")
```

Comment: I see this works, but iis there a way to achieve this by overriding present function instead?

Comment: This answer is only valid for learning purposes. In a real production-grade code you should never establish your navigation logic inside other instances of the navigation objects. The navigation events should be propagated to an outer layer and handled outside. I also did remove the downvote after realizing that it does not hinder the quality of the answer.

Comment: @IsaacCarolWeisberg Can you please elaborate how the above code violates the navigation logic. And what other instance are you talking about. Please explain your comment.

Comment: @PGDev yes, sir. Thing is, if you call your presents/navigationController.push's inside the UIViewController you are navigating from, this introduces an unnecessary coupling of the controllers, increasing the technical debt. Alternatively you could use a Coordinator pattern and have this logic easily managed outside the instances, only introducing a way to emit navigation requests. +150 to code's maintainability.

Comment: @PGDev the reason i wanted to do this was so that I don't have to enforce other developer to call the function instead of present. So I wanted to keep all the callbacks of present. But it looks like your suggestion is the only valid way. Thank  you!

Answer (score 0):

Overrides of NSObject's derivatives in Swift's static extensions is only for Objective-C compatibility. You cannot `override` in extensions of pure Swift declarations. Think of it in such manner that if the class itself adds an override, and then a static extension adds an override. Which implementation should the linker link? And which implementation does `super` call refer to? In Objective-C this behavior is undefined, in Swift the extension override is ignored all together.

What you could do instead is move the overriding function from the extension directly to the class.